# How to truncate decimal type & preserve as decimal type without rounding?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to truncate decimal types without rounding & retain the decimal type, in the most processor efficient way possible.

The Math options I believe returns a float.

The quantize option returns a rounded number I believe.

Str options are way to processor costly.

Is there a simple, direct way to simply cut the digits off a decimal type past a specified decimal length?

Comment: Do you want to actually truncate the numeric value, or do you need a string representation of the value with a given number of digits?

Comment: I need the end result to be a Decimal type.  I don't want to convert in and out of str. I have hella lot of numbers to process.  That would add too much to the processing time.

Comment: When you say `decimal` you mean `decimal.Decimal`?

Comment: If processing time is an issue: Are you sure you need `Decimal`? Or can you get away with `float`s (maybe using `numpy`), which is probably inherently faster?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [`quantize`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.quantize) method does have a `rounding` parameter which controls how the value is rounded. The [`ROUND_DOWN`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.Context) option seems to do what you want:

> - `ROUND_DOWN` (towards zero)

```
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_DOWN

def truncate_decimal(d, places):
    """Truncate Decimal d to the given number of places.

    >>> truncate_decimal(Decimal('1.234567'), 4)
    Decimal('1.2345')
    >>> truncate_decimal(Decimal('-0.999'), 1)
    Decimal('-0.9')
    """
    return d.quantize(Decimal(10) ** -places, rounding=ROUND_DOWN)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you can use `divmod` (it's a build-in function). It splits a number into integer and decimal parts:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> d1 = decimal.Decimal(3.14)
>>> divmod(d1, 1)[0]
Decimal('3')
>>> d2 = decimal.Decimal(5.64)
>>> divmod(d2, 1)[0]
Decimal('5')
```

Answer (score -1):

To cut off decimals past (for example) the second decimal place:

```
from math import floor
x = 3.14159
x2 = floor(x * 100) / 100
```